GPU usage in Beeware similar to Kivy
I want to do image processing using opencv and make it an android app.
Because my main codes are written in Python and I don't intend to use Java or Kotlin, I plan to convert the Python codes into an Android app.
I have 2 ways. Kivy and Beeware
My processing is light but with high numbers and I must use GPU. Kivy gives me this possibility. But I don't know if it is possible to use graphic and parallel process in Beeware or not? Can anyone guide me?
For example, I use cuda on a desktop system. But when I want to run my app on the Android system, I should be able to use openGL instead of cuda. Is it possible to write a program with python and openGL with beeware on Android or not?

BeeWare certainly supports parallel multithreading on Android. But what do you mean by Kivy having the possibility to use the GPU? Please edit your question to give some documentation links, or example code.

I mean Is it possible to write a program with python and openGL with beeware on Android or not?

Kivy uses OpenGL for displaying its user interface, but as far as I know, neither Kivy nor BeeWare supports any GPU acceleration of OpenCV. If you've read otherwise, please post the link.

According to this article, kivy is gpu accelerated. May helps https://www.thecyberiatech.com/blog/mobile-app/kivy-vs-beeware/

That article is almost certainly only talking about the GUI. And BeeWare's GUI is equally GPU-accelerated, because it uses Android's native Views API. But neither of those will help speed up OpenCV.
